# PySpark: how to groupby, resample and forward-fill null values?

Tags: python, pyspark

Considering the below dataset *in Spark*, I would like to resample the dates with a specific frequency (eg. 5 minutes).

```
START_DATE = dt.datetime(2019,8,15,20,33,0)
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'school_id': ['remote','remote','remote','remote','onsite','onsite','onsite','onsite','remote','remote'],
    'class_id': ['green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'green'],
    'user_id': [15,15,16,16,15,17,17,17,16,17],
    'status': [0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0],
    'start': pd.date_range(start=START_DATE, periods=10, freq='2min')
})

test_df.groupby(['school_id', 'class_id', 'user_id', 'start']).min()
```

However I also want the resample to happen between two specific date ranges: `2019-08-15 20:30:00` and `2019-08-15 21:00:00`. So every group of `school_id`, `class_id` and `user_id` will have 6 entries, one every 5 min bucket between the two date ranges.
The `null` entries generated by the resample should be populated by forward-fill.

I've used Pandas for the sample dataset, but the actual dataframe will be pulled in Spark, so the approach I'm looking for should be done in Spark as well.

I guess the approach might be similar to this one [PySpark: how to resample frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271374/pyspark-how-to-resample-frequencies) but I'm not getting it to work in this scenario.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This probably is not the best way to get the final results, but just want to show the idea here.

1. First, create the DataFrame and convert from timestamp to integers

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from pytz import timezone

# Create DataFrame
START_DATE = datetime(2019,8,15,20,33,0)
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'school_id': ['remote','remote','remote','remote','onsite','onsite','onsite','onsite','remote','remote'],
    'class_id': ['green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'green'],
    'user_id': [15,15,16,16,15,17,17,17,16,17],
    'status': [0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0],
    'start': pd.date_range(start=START_DATE, periods=10, freq='2min')
})

# Convert TimeStamp to Integers
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_df)
print(df.dtypes)
df = df.withColumn('start', F.col('start').cast("bigint"))
df.show()
```

This outputs:

```
+---------+--------+-------+------+----------+
|school_id|class_id|user_id|status|     start|
+---------+--------+-------+------+----------+
|   remote|   green|     15|     0|1565915580|
|   remote|   green|     15|     1|1565915700|
|   remote|     red|     16|     1|1565915820|
|   remote|     red|     16|     1|1565915940|
|   onsite|   green|     15|     0|1565916060|
|   onsite|   green|     17|     1|1565916180|
|   onsite|   green|     17|     0|1565916300|
|   onsite|   green|     17|     1|1565916420|
|   remote|     red|     16|     1|1565916540|
|   remote|   green|     17|     0|1565916660|
+---------+--------+-------+------+----------+
```

2. Create the time sequences you want

```
# Create time sequece needed
start = datetime.strptime('2019-08-15 20:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
start = eastern.localize(start)
times = pd.date_range(start = start, periods = 6, freq='5min')
times = [s.timestamp() for s in times]
print(times)
```

```
[1565915400.0, 1565915700.0, 1565916000.0, 1565916300.0, 1565916600.0, 1565916900.0]
```

3. Finally, create dataframe for each group

```
# Use pandas_udf to create final DataFrame
schm = StructType(df.schema.fields + [StructField('epoch', IntegerType(), True)])
@pandas_udf(schm, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def resample(pdf):
    pddf = pd.DataFrame({'epoch':times})
    pddf['school_id'] = pdf['school_id'][0]
    pddf['class_id'] = pdf['class_id'][0]
    pddf['user_id'] = pdf['user_id'][0]


    res = np.searchsorted(times, pdf['start'])
    arr = np.zeros(len(times))
    arr[:] = np.nan
    arr[res] = pdf['start']
    pddf['status'] = arr

    arr[:] = np.nan
    arr[res] = pdf['status']
    pddf['start'] = arr
    return pddf

df = df.groupBy('school_id', 'class_id', 'user_id').apply(resample)
df = df.withColumn('timestamp', F.to_timestamp(df['epoch']))
df.show(60)
```

The Final results:

```
+---------+--------+-------+----------+-----+----------+-------------------+
|school_id|class_id|user_id|    status|start|     epoch|          timestamp|
+---------+--------+-------+----------+-----+----------+-------------------+
|   remote|     red|     16|      null| null|1565915400|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|   remote|     red|     16|      null| null|1565915700|2019-08-15 20:35:00|
|   remote|     red|     16|1565915940|    1|1565916000|2019-08-15 20:40:00|
|   remote|     red|     16|      null| null|1565916300|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|   remote|     red|     16|1565916540|    1|1565916600|2019-08-15 20:50:00|
|   remote|     red|     16|      null| null|1565916900|2019-08-15 20:55:00|
|   onsite|   green|     15|      null| null|1565915400|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|   onsite|   green|     15|      null| null|1565915700|2019-08-15 20:35:00|
|   onsite|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916000|2019-08-15 20:40:00|
|   onsite|   green|     15|1565916060|    0|1565916300|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|   onsite|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916600|2019-08-15 20:50:00|
|   onsite|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916900|2019-08-15 20:55:00|
|   remote|   green|     17|      null| null|1565915400|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|   remote|   green|     17|      null| null|1565915700|2019-08-15 20:35:00|
|   remote|   green|     17|      null| null|1565916000|2019-08-15 20:40:00|
|   remote|   green|     17|      null| null|1565916300|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|   remote|   green|     17|      null| null|1565916600|2019-08-15 20:50:00|
|   remote|   green|     17|1565916660|    0|1565916900|2019-08-15 20:55:00|
|   onsite|   green|     17|      null| null|1565915400|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|   onsite|   green|     17|      null| null|1565915700|2019-08-15 20:35:00|
|   onsite|   green|     17|      null| null|1565916000|2019-08-15 20:40:00|
|   onsite|   green|     17|1565916180|    1|1565916300|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|   onsite|   green|     17|1565916420|    1|1565916600|2019-08-15 20:50:00|
|   onsite|   green|     17|      null| null|1565916900|2019-08-15 20:55:00|
|   remote|   green|     15|      null| null|1565915400|2019-08-15 20:30:00|
|   remote|   green|     15|1565915580|    0|1565915700|2019-08-15 20:35:00|
|   remote|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916000|2019-08-15 20:40:00|
|   remote|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916300|2019-08-15 20:45:00|
|   remote|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916600|2019-08-15 20:50:00|
|   remote|   green|     15|      null| null|1565916900|2019-08-15 20:55:00|
+---------+--------+-------+----------+-----+----------+-------------------+
```

Now you get 6 timestamps for each group.
Note, not all the original 'status' and 'start' are mapped to the final DataFrame, that's because in the `resample` udf, it happens for `5minute` interval, two 'start' times can map to the same time grid point, you lose one here. This can be tuned in the `udf` based on your frequency and how you want to keep the data.