# Going from pandas to pyspark - Convert dataframe with start and end date to daily data?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, reshape, melt

I have an ETL script using Pandas, and to make it more scalable I am trying to recreate it with Pyspark. Got everything going so far, but having issues with a particular transformation to a daily dataset. I have one record per ID with start date and end date

```
id  age state   start_date  end_date
123 18  CA     2/17/2019    5/4/2019
223 24  AZ     1/17/2019    3/4/2019
```

I want to create a record for each day between the start and end day, so I can join daily activity data to it. The target output would look something like this

```
id  age state   start_date
123 18  CA      2/17/2019
123 18  CA      2/18/2019
123 18  CA      2/19/2019
123 18  CA      2/20/2019
123 18  CA      2/21/2019
            …
123 18  CA      5/2/2019
123 18  CA      5/3/2019
123 18  CA      5/4/2019
```

And of course do this for all ids and their respective start dates in the dataset. I was able to do this in Pandas using the following approach

```
melt = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'age', 'state'], value_name='date').drop('variable', axis=1)
melt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(melt['date'])

melt = melt.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('d').first())\
           .ffill()\
           .reset_index(level=1)\
           .reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I am fairly new to Pyspark (and was struggling with this in Pandas) so I'm stuck here. Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark: how to resample frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271374/pyspark-how-to-resample-frequencies)

Comment: Definitely looks like a good place to start. Thanks!

Comment: So that's getting closer, but I'm not clear on how to do this across multiple ids? Basically, in the example he creates a time series with the required intervals, and then joining the observations from a single variable back to it. But in my case each ID should have the range of daily intervals, and these intervals will be different for each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/end-to-end-time-series-interpolation-in-pyspark-filling-the-gap-5ccefc6b7fc9). The key for my solution was the explode function, which does what I need.

The code to solve my specific example is

```
def date_range(t1, t2, step=60*60*24):
    return [t1 + step*x for x in range(int((t2-t1)/step)+1)]

date_range_udf = udf(date_range, ArrayType(LongType()))

df = dataF.select("id",
expr("stack(2, 'start_date', start_date, 'end_date', end_date) as (class_date,date)"))

df_base = \
    df.groupBy('id')\
        .agg(min('date').cast('integer').alias('date_min'), max('date').cast('integer')\
    .alias('date_max'))\
        .withColumn("date", explode(date_range_udf("date_min", "date_max")))\
        .drop('date_min', 'date_max')\
        .withColumn("date", from_unixtime("date"))
```

Which gives the following output (which I can use to join any additional data)

[image]